# mysql query add [something]_ infront of all table rows when grabbing multiple tables

Tags: sql, mysql

Example of what I want to do:
select a.* as a_*, b.* as b_* FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.id

Comment: I do most by hand when I only new a few but this contains 50 or more so was just seeing if there was an easier way. I could just do a loop of the table with php and auto create the manual list. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot be done automatically in SQL. Either type or generate the following:

```
SELECT a.field AS a_field, a.field2 AS a_field2, ...
```

At any rate, listing the fields by hand is good practice anyways.